# Does the ulkJSON library have limitations when dealing with base64 in Delphi 7?

Tags: json, delphi, rest

I'm working on a project that is using Delphi 7 to consume RESTful services.  We are creating and decoding JSON with the [ulkJSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) library. Up to this point I've been able to successfully build and send JSON containing a base64 string that exceed 5,160kb.  I can verify that the base64 is being received by the services and verify the integrity of the base64 once its there.  In addition to sending, I can also receive and successfully decode JSON with a smaller (~ 256KB or less) base64.

However I am experiencing some issues on the return trip when larger (~1,024KB+) base64 is involved for some reason.  Specifically when attempting to use the following JSON format and function combination:

JSON:

```
{ 
    "message" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD...." 
}
```

Function:

```
function checkResults(JSONFormattedString: String): String;
var
  jsonObject          : TlkJSONObject;
  iteration           : Integer;
  i                   : Integer;
  x                   : Integer;
begin
  jsonObject := TlkJSONobject.Create;

  // Validate that the JSONFormatted string is not empty.
  // If it is empty, inform the user/programmer, and exit from this routine.
  if JSONFormattedString = '' then
    begin
        result := 'Error: JSON returned is Null';
        jsonObject.Free;
        exit;
    end;

  // Now that we can validate that this string is not empty, we are going to
  // assume that the string is a JSONFormatted string and attempt to parse it.
  //
  // If the string is not a valid JSON object (such as an http status code)
  // throw an exception informing the user/programmer that an unexpected value
  // has been passed. And exit from this routine.
  try
    jsonObject := TlkJSON.ParseText(JSONFormattedString) as TlkJSONobject;
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
        result := 'Error: No JSON was received from web services';
        jsonObject.Free;
        exit;
    end;
  end;

  // Now that the object has been parsed, lets check the contents.
  try
      result := jsonObject.Field['message'].value;
      jsonObject.Free;
      exit;
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
      result := 'Error: No Message received from Web Services '+e.message;
      jsonObject.Free;
      exit;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

As mentioned above when using the above function, I am able to get small (256KB and less) base64 strings out of the 'message' field of a JSON object.  But for some reason if the received JSON is larger than say 1,024kb the following line seems to just stop in its tracks:

```
    jsonObject := TlkJSON.ParseText(JSONFormattedString) as TlkJSONobject;
```

No errors, no results.  Following the debugger, I can go into the library, and see that the JSON string being passed is not considered to be JSON despite being in the format listed above.  The only difference I can find between calls that work as expected and calls that do not work as expect appears to be the size of base64 being transmitted.

Am I missing something completely obvious and should be shot for my code implementation (very possible)?  Have I missed some notation regarding the limitations of the ulkJSON library?  Any input would be extremely helpful.  Thanks in advance stack!

Comment: I can answer *some* of your questions, but not all of them. The JSON library trivially has limitations when dealing with base64 in the sense that it's completely agnostic about it. There are several bugs in your code (memory leaks, poor exception handling, cumbersome error reporting), but none that would affect a length limit of a JSON string value. You should use your debugger to explore where in the JSON parser the program gets stuck, and you can write a simple test to determine what the actual length limit is (instead of just guessing it's "say, 1024KB").

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for your response! I knew the code wasn't the greatest, but pretty surprised to see I'm missing those bugs.  I'm following your advise in going through the debugger and testing the length limit.  I will post my findings as soon as they become available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investigating this for hours over the course of some time, I did discover that the library indeed was working properly and there was no issue.

The issue came down to the performance of my machine as it was taking on average 215802 milliseconds (3.5967 minutes) to process a moderately sized image (1.2 meg) in base64 format.  This performance scaled according to the size of the base64 string (faster for smaller, longer for larger).